# Identify court that issued a warrant?

Tags: united-states, massachusetts

If a person or business gets searched and the police do not provide the owner of the place with a copy of the warrant, then the searchee has the problem of determining what court or judge issued the warrant in order to contest the warrant or get a copy of it. How can they determine this?

There are two ways to answer this question. If there is a specific procedure or method for finding out which judge/court issued a warrant for **Massachusetts**, then that would be a direct answer. Note: "ask the police" is not an answer. Assume for the purpose of this question that the police are either unavailable or refuse to say anything about the warrant, as is their right.

The second way to answer the question would be to identify all the judges that *could* issue the warrant. This is an answer because if the searchee knows all the courts that could issue the warrant, then they can simply go to each one and ask them if they issued the warrant in question. So, if you can describe how to determine what courts can possibly issue a warrant for a particular place, then that is an answer.

Comment: You could clarify 'as is their right' somewhat for those of us who live under different legal assumptions. How is searching without a warrant any different from searching with a warrant that you refuse to show anybody? Does a warrant signed by Donald Duck allow the police in?

Comment: @TimLymington Police in the United States do not have to show the warrant to anyone. They just need to have possession of it. (In the UK, by comparison, the police do not need a warrant at all. They just need to "arrest" someone on the property to search it. So, they just wait till the guy gets home, arrest him on some pretext, then they can search the whole house, no warrant needed at all.)